# Windows Error PythonService was unable to locate the service manager

Tags: python, service, pywin32

Currently experiencing this issue on my Windows machine when installing a Windows Service. This is the error output I get from running in the cmd as administrator. Restricting me from being able to run my services.

- PythonService was unable to locate the service manager. Please see the event log for details.

Here is the output from event viewer application log:

```
The description for Event ID 14 from source Python Service cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

<Error getting traceback - traceback.print_exception() failed>

The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file
```

This issue has happened on each of these version I've tested Python3.11, 3.10.10 and 3.10.8.

Currently running Python 3.10.8 64 Bit on Windows Server 2016.

- I've installed pywin32
- Run post_install in the root directory of python310
- Installed the service with install flag
- Attempted to start service with start flag
- PythonService was unable to locate the service manager. Please see the event log for details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I found out it was because I was using a virtual environment (venv). I assume your also using a venv, since if u weren't u wouldn't have this issue. I have run a bare minimum service in a venv and it returned the error provided in your question, when i ran it from the main interpreter it ran just fine. I don't know why it doesn't work in a venv, I have tried to find a solution for hours.

Comment: No actually this is using the global pip packages. I found backdating to python 3.9 resolved my issue. The issue persisted across 3.10, 11 and 12.